# Invalid parameter type android.content.SharedPreference in Xamarin Android binding

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, sharedpreferences, xamarin-binding

We are trying to create a binding library for Android aar. we are not able to see binder class in output dll. we are getting following warning which is invalidating the class.

> BINDINGSGENERATOR: Warning BG8801: Invalid parameter type android.content.SharedPreferences in method Clear in managed type Com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.
>
> BINDINGSGENERATOR: Warning BG8701: Invalid return type android.content.SharedPreferences in method GetStorage in managed type Com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could provide the code, which line thrown the exception?

Comment: void clear(SharedPreferences preferences);                                  SharedPreferences getStorage();                                                                      simple code in one of our files in aar.